# Get sum of values month, year wise using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Below is the data that I have:

[There are three columns the class, date and marks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yLtj.png)

I need my output to be in the format below:
[Here column headers 1,2,3 are the classes which contain the total marks stored month and year wise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jI8Wl.png)

My approach to this was using the following logic:
(Although I get the result, I am not satisfied with the code. I was hoping that someone could help me with a more efficient solution for the same?)

```
class=sorted(df.Class.unique())
dict_all = dict.fromkeys(class , 1)
for c in class:
    actuals=[]
    for i in range(2018,2019):
       for j in range(1,13):
          a = df['date'].map(lambda x : x.year == i)
          b = df['date'].map(lambda x : x.month == j)
          x= df[a & b & (df.class==c)].marks.sum()
          actuals.append(x)
     dict_all[c]=actuals
result = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict_all)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how-to-pivot-a-dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-to-pivot-a-dataframe)

Answer (score 0):

Input:

```
   Class        Date  Total
0      3  01-01-2018     32
1      2  01-01-2018     69
2      1  01-01-2018    129
3      3  01-01-2019     12
```

Using `df.pivot`

```
df1 = df.pivot(index="Date",columns="Class", values="Total", ).reset_index().fillna(0)
print(df1)
```

Using `crosstab`

```
df1 = pd.crosstab(index=df["Date"],columns=df["Class"], values=df["Total"],aggfunc="max").reset_index().fillna(0)
print(df1)
```

Using `groupby & unstack()`

```
df1 = df.groupby(['Date','Class'])['Total'].max().unstack(fill_value=0).reset_index()
print(df1)
```

All the code(s) gives the output:

```
Class        Date    1   2   3
0      01-01-2018  129  69  32
1      01-01-2019    0   0  12
```